# HELP! Need help with wifi, it keeps disconnecting in an odd way

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

I am having problems with my WiFi on Ubuntu. After 4-6 minutes I cant access the internet even though it shows that I am still connected. I have no problems with the WiFi on any other device at home or when I use windows. I have been trying to use Ubuntu as my main OS but this wifi problem is making it unusable and an extreme hassle.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:0060 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:021e Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:0502 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:17ba ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N10 Nano 802.11n Network Adapter [Realtek RTL8192CU]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 30:9c:23:07:ad:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 498  bytes 43657 (43.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 498  bytes 43657 (43.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx88d7f6061b8e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.151  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::c6b0:9a6c:5e9f:d9a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 88:d7:f6:06:1b:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 3252  bytes 3121913 (3.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2566  bytes 362022 (362.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lsmod | grep rtl
  rtl8xxxu              126976  0
  rtl8192cu              69632  0
  rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
  rtl8192c_common        57344  1 rtl8192cu
  rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
  mac80211              782336  4 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8xxxu
  cfg80211              614400  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

Edit:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlx -e rtl
[   10.281634] usb 1-10: rtl8192cu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x80 bytes):
[   10.281652] usb 1-10: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   11.204169] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[   12.142173] rtl8xxxu 1-10:1.0 wlx88d7f6061b8e: renamed from wlan0
[   21.734810] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx88d7f6061b8e: link is not ready
[   21.738882] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx88d7f6061b8e: link is not ready
[   22.336831] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx88d7f6061b8e: link is not ready
[   24.600867] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18
[   24.605979] wlx88d7f6061b8e: send auth to 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[   24.607334] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticated
[   24.608168] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[   24.615359] wlx88d7f6061b8e: RX AssocResp from 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=15)
[   24.615926] usb 1-10: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported
[   24.616528] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associated
[   24.616535] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx88d7f6061b8e: link becomes ready
[  139.804740] wlx88d7f6061b8e: deauthenticating from 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  142.096664] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18
[  142.099742] wlx88d7f6061b8e: send auth to 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[  142.104101] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticated
[  142.108046] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[  142.116296] wlx88d7f6061b8e: RX AssocResp from 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=15)
[  142.116928] usb 1-10: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported
[  142.117649] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associated
[  190.224452] wlx88d7f6061b8e: disassociated from 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[  191.337207] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18
[  191.343266] wlx88d7f6061b8e: send auth to 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[  191.346611] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticated
[  191.348112] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[  191.351230] wlx88d7f6061b8e: RX AssocResp from 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=15)
[  191.351815] usb 1-10: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported
[  191.352555] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associated
[  417.076676] wlx88d7f6061b8e: deauthenticating from 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  422.665477] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18
[  422.668437] wlx88d7f6061b8e: send auth to 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[  422.669771] wlx88d7f6061b8e: authenticated
[  422.672046] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associate with 00:12:2a:87:e8:18 (try 1/3)
[  422.676420] wlx88d7f6061b8e: RX AssocResp from 00:12:2a:87:e8:18     (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=15)
[  422.676975] usb 1-10: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported
[  422.677789] wlx88d7f6061b8e: associated

nmcli dev wifi list
*  SSID                              MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
DIRECT-88-HP DeskJet 4530 series  Infra  13    54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
*    NETIASPOT-87E810                  Infra  13    54 Mbit/s  58      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
LLOYD                             Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2      
VICTORIA                          Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

Comment: still no luck, would you recommend that I get a different WiFi adapter or are there other things I should try first? I already turned off power saving.

Comment: still no luck, would you recommend that I get a different WiFi adapter or are there other things I should try first? I already turned off power saving.

Answer (score 0):

As we see, there are two possibly conflicting drivers loaded for the ASUS wireless; let's try blacklisting one to see if stability improves:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

I also suggest a change to Network Manager to disable power saving:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Then restart Network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Is there any improvement?

**EDIT**: For privacy reasons, the default settings for Ubuntu 17.04's (and later) network manager causes the MAC address of the USB Wifi device to change constantly. To fix this, you just have to edit a configuration file and then restart the network-manager service.

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor and run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: I implemented the proposed changes, I will get back to everyone tomorrow and let you all know if it works or I am, still having problems.

Comment: OK so it did not take long for the same issue to happen again, are there any other things that I can try doing or should i just buy a different wifi adapter? I don't mind getting a new one if it will fix the problem but im not sure if that will even solve whats going on.

Comment: Let's see if we can gather some clues from the log: `dmesg | grep -e wlx -e rtl` and also: `nmcli dev wifi list`

Comment: I added both as an edit to my main post, thanks for taking the time to help me out

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.